# Wijmo Linechart: Controlling X-Axis labels for Dates/Strings

Tags: linechart, componentone, wijmo

I am displaying data in a Wijmo Linechart whose X value is a time of day.  eg, 8:00, 8:05, 8:10, and so on.  Even though my data points are every 5 minutes, I would like my X-Axis labels to show only for the whole hour.  eg, 8:00, 9:00, 10:00, and so on.

Currently, I can only get the X-Axis labels to reflect the actual values of the datapoint.  eg, every 5 minutes.

Can someone lead me in the right direction?  Thanks.

Comment: Can anyone give me some insight on this?

Answer (score 2):

Are you binding the data to the Label and not the series though.  It looks like you are returning your value and putting it in the label.

```
            seriesList: [{
                legendEntry: true,
                label: "timeData",
                data: { x: { bind: "Date" }, y: { bind: "Count"} }
            }]
```

> **Note**: I was going to answer your question, but I realized I was pulling the answer from the [wijmo forums and it was to your
>   question](http://wijmo.com/topic/wijmo-linechart-controlling-x-axis-labels-for-datesstrings/).